# Prove or disprove vector space in R3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I've been working on this problem quite a long time:
[Prove or disprove R3 is a vector space under these operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFSDC.png)

1. For the first one i have used the vectors $(1, 1, -2)$ & $(1, 2, -3)$ to test for closure under vector addition - which turns out to be true.

i.e. $(1+1)+(1+2)+(-2+(-3)) = (1+1+(-2))+(1+2+(-3)) =0$ (as per book Linear Algebra - Jim Hefferon pg-82)

2. Whereas for scalar multiplication, I have used scalar value 2, this also turns to be true

i.e. using vector $(1,1,-2)$ : $2(1+1+(-2)) = 2+2+(-4) = 0$ (as per book Linear Algebra - Jim Hefferon pg-83)

As for part (b) the vector addition condition is the same as part (a), so the vector addition proves to be true, as for the scalar multiplication it fails,

test result: 2 $(1, 1, -2) = (2, 2, -4)$ not equal to $(0, 0, 0)$

I know I'm getting it wrong on both parts as the answer in the booklet is [not a vector space under these conditions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT4DX.png)

Does this mean I've got the whole vector space concept wrong?

Apologies for the formatting.

Awaiting for your views... Thanks

Comment: Hint:  what is the additive identity element?

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that a set equipped with vector space structure must also be a commutative group with respect to addition.

And every group must have an identity.

Can you find any identity in this group?.

For example. if $(a,b,c)$ be the identity under such a binary composition. Then when I add it to any vector I must get back the same vector .

$(1,1,1)+(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$.

But this cannot hold as $(1,1,1)+(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ for all $(x,y,z)$.

So this set does not have identity under this binary composition(when addition is defined in this weird way) . Hence it is not a group under addition. Hence it cannot be a vector space.

Comment: still a bit confused about the identity thing... but why the book showed another answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "another answer'? If you mean that the book says that this is not a vector space when you think it is, YOU ARE WRONG.  This is not a vector space because there is no "additive identity"  An additive identity is a vector (normally called "0" but that does NOT mean that it has to have 0 components or, indeed, any  components  at all.)  such that for any vector, v, 0+ v= v.  Here any vector+ v= 0, not v!

Comment: @rajbabna I think you should look up binary operations and just read about some elementary results about group theory . Or even you can try and verify the 10 axioms that a vector space satisfy. You will see that this does not satisfy the criteria of existence of a null vector which when added to another non-null vector should give you the non-null vector

Comment: thks guys seems that there's a lot of work to do before understanding the logic behind vector space.

Comment: @rajbabna No not really. binary operations are taught in class 12 in Indian schools both in CBSE and ICSE boards. And I think each year there is a compulsory question on binary operations and specifically finding the identity element under the binary operation. For example if I tell you that the operation is "+" of matrices. Then A+O = A for all matrix A. But if I say the operation is "." then A.I = A. But O is the null matrix and I is the identity. They are different. It all depends on the context of the binary operation you are dealing with.

Comment: a big thanks to both of you guys Mr.Gandalf Sauron and @user247327 for your explanations. Will read more on group theory, hope this will clear the murkiness of Vector space...lol

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like  you are completely misunderstanding the problem!

In the first, you have addition defined by $(x_1, y_1, z_1)+ (x_2, y_2, z_2)= =(0, 0, 0)$.  You have chosen to use vectors (1, 1, -2) and (1, 2, -3) so that the sum of the individual elements, 1+ 1- 2+ 1+ 2- 3, is equal to 0.  That's not the point!

The point is that the sum of any vectors is 0!  (1, 1, 1)+ (3, 3, 3) is not "1+ 1+ 1+ 3+ 3+ 3= 12".  it is 0, BY DEFINITION

To prove that this is or is not a vector space you have to check the axioms for a vector space
u+ v= v+ u.  That's true because, no matter what u and v are, both u+ v and v+ u are 0.  u+ (v+ w)= (u+ v)+ w.  Again both sides are 0. a(u+ v)= au+ av. Again both sides are 0. For any v, there exit a "0" vector such that u+ 0= u.   Oops!  Every sum is 0 and u may not be 0.

Comment: if i got it right:

Comment: All this time I did miss the logic behind vector space, correct me if i'm wrong for a vector space to exist the R.H.S defines the rules for a vector space to exist, in this case 0. The axioms are used to justify existence of vector space under the conditions by definition. Apologies for this dumb question, every 8 axioms should give zero, which is not the case here... thks again

Comment: I have no idea what "every 8 axioms should give zero" is intended to mean.

Comment: I should have written, for a vector space to exist it should satisfy the 8 axioms, and not "every axioms should give zero". Anyway thanks for your help I did manage to get full mark for this question...